# Key not found exception pivot wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

On my detail.xaml

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    this.PageTitle.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["lineone"];
    this.Contents.Text = NavigationContext.QueryString["linethree"];
    //populate book text control here
}
```

but when i enter lineone in place of line three it works fine except it shows the data of line one in the contents section.

I am using default pivot based layout for windows phone 7

Answer (score 2):

If you attempt to access a key that isn't found, you get a exception.

So instead of `NavigationContext.QueryString["key"]` you should use [`NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("key")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299639%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)